# Managed USB Switch

Tags: usb, ip, remote, switch, kvm-switch

We have 4 computers controlled by an KVM-over-IP switch, so we can **remotely** control the keyboard and the mouse and can see the screens. 
Now, we need to connect an usb flash device to that computers - and attach and detach it remotely.

So we are searching for a USB switch, which connects one slave to different hosts (note: not a hub, which connectes multiple slaves to one host) and can be controlled remotely - preferable by IP.

The only idea we found so far is to combine a **Max Value MV44222 4port USB-Switch** with a **Raspberry Pi**, but we would actually prefer something prebuild...

What can we do?

Comment: Product requests are off-topic for SU, if that's what you are looking for. Otherwise, your question is too broad and unclear.  If you think you should combine a USB switch and a RaspPi, sound good. Where are you getting stuck exactly?

Comment: This will be tough to find.  A USB Switch would be difficult to design if only for the fact, storage devices would be hell to manage, you can't simply disconnect a storage device from one computer and connect it to another computer and not expect something bad to happen.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen USB-to-Ethernet adapters that were designed with USB printers in mind, but will work for other USB devices.  We trialed one at my work; basically there was a client that got installed on each computer that wanted to use the USB device, and they could take control of it and "own" it while they needed it, and then release it when they were done.  Sounds like what you're after?